# Edit textbox in parallel to asynchronous updating

Tags: c#, asynchronous, textbox

So in my project I have a few textBoxes that hold the coordinates of two corners (Latitude & Longitude). The textBoxes are updated by a timer (which gets a value from a server and sets the textBoxes if the value received is different from the current value). Problem is, I want the textBoxes to be available for manual editing; However if I'm in the middle of typing the number and the timer checks the current value he sees that it's a different thing from what the server returned and changes it immediately. Is there a way to check if the textBox is being edited at the moment, or a better way to solve this solution?

code (samples, the code is the same for the two corners):

```
if (northEastLatitude != double.Parse(neLatTB.Text)) //neLatTB is the textBox
      neLatTB.Text = northEastLatitude.ToString();


else //No answer returned from the server so we need to reset the textBoxes
{
      northEastLatitude = 0;
      northEastLongitude = 0;
      if(neLatTB.Text != "0")
             neLatTB.Text = northEastLatitude.ToString();
      if(neLngTB.Text != "0")
             neLngTB.Text = northEastLongitude.ToString();
}
```

in addition, I have functions for TextChanged events for all of the textBoxes (so that when I set the coordinates manually it uploads them to the server). Is there any way to prevent this function from being called whenever I press the dot key? apparently it calls the event too (marks the ending of the text entering).

Comment: Is it WinForms or WPF?

Comment: No problem, posted what I would do if had simillar problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your design but if you want to use `TextBox` to show updatable values and also make it possible to edit you have to suppress code from your timer to execute. WinForms `TextBox` doesn't have an option to show you if text is changing programmatically or by user interaction. You have to somehow make it by yourself.

There is plenty of ways to do that of courde. One way is to use `Enter`/`Leave` events to detect when your `TextBox` gets or loses focus. But there will be a need to click somwhere out from the control after edit.

Another one, and probably desired by you would be using `TextChanged` event preventing your timer from updating field until text in `TextBox` will be typed in full. I would do it something like that:

Fisrtly I would declare two `bool` variables for blocking parts of code from execution:

```
private bool _isDirty; // used when user types text directly
private bool _suppresTextChanged; // used when timer updates value programmatically
```

After that I would write `TextBox.TextChanged` event listener:

```
private void neLatTBTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(_suppressTextChanged)
        return;
    _isDirty = true; // toggle dirty state

    if(/* text has good format */)
    {
        // Upload changes to server
        _isDirty = false; // end manual edit mode
    }
}
```

And inside timer method i would set:

```
_suppresTextChanged = true; // on the beginning

if (northEastLatitude != double.Parse(neLatTB.Text)) //neLatTB is the textBox
  neLatTB.Text = northEastLatitude.ToString();
else //No answer returned from the server so we need to reset the textBoxes
{
      northEastLatitude = 0;
      northEastLongitude = 0;
      if(neLatTB.Text != "0")
             neLatTB.Text = northEastLatitude.ToString();
      if(neLngTB.Text != "0")
             neLngTB.Text = northEastLongitude.ToString();
}

_suppresTextChanged = false; // after edit was made
```

Personally i think this design can lead to a lot of problems (consider what to do when user stops typing and leave the `TextBox` in `_isDirty` state etc...). Instead of using just `TextBox` I would add a `Label` to store data from timer (and probably data the user will type) and left `TextBox` just for entering user specific values.